# How do I apply a class to multiple images with one tag?

Tags: css

I'm trying to apply a class to multiple images.  For example:

```
<img class="test" src="great.jpg" />
<img class="test" src="hello.jpg" />
<img class="test" src="pie.jpg" />
```

How do I wrap all of those images with one tag to apply the 'test' class to all of them without having to specify the class in every single image tag? In the stylesheet I have:

```
img.test {
border: 4px solid black;
}
```

I tried wrapping the images with a div and then a span tag with the class as test, but nothing.  Help please??  Thanks!!

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Answer (score 3):

markup:

```
<div class="test">
    <img src="great.jpg" />
    <img src="hello.jpg" />
    <img src="pie.jpg" />
</div>
```

css:

```
.test img
{
    border: 4px solid black;
}
```

[**edit**]: Check out [w3.org's Selectors Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/) and, specifically, [descendant combinators](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators).

Answer (score 1):

Css descendant selector!

HTML:

```
<div class="test">
  <img src="great.jpg" />
  <img src="hello.jpg" />
  <img src="pie.jpg" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.test img {
  border: 4px solid black;
}
```